# Cannot extend a list based on HTML table using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read HTML tables and send the contents to a list of tuples of a fixed size of 28 elements. Some of the HTML tables give either out of the index or are less in the size.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_table = r"""<html>
<body>
someother stuff
<table class="data-table">
  <tr>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td> 

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2c1</td>
    <td>r2c2</td> 

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r3c1</td>
    <td>r3c2</td> 

  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_table, 'html.parser')
```

I tried the following:

```
 table_rows =[['a','a1'],['b','b1']...['z','z1']]

 characteristics=[]
 tb = soup.find('table', class_='data-table')

 tr_len = len(tb.find_all('tr'))
 mycount = 0

 for tr in tb.find_all('tr'):
     tds = tr.find_all('td') 
     colname = str(tds[0].text.strip())
     newcolname = table_rows[mycount][1]
     if colname == newcolname:
         characteristics.append([tds[0].text.strip(), tds[1].text.strip()]) 
     else:
         characteristics.insert(mycount+1, [colname,"Nothing"]) 

     mycount = mycount+1
```

My goal is if a column does not exist in tds add it and place a value of nothing in list characteristics

I want to create a list of

```
column1_value, column2_value, column3_value, column4_value, column5_value, column6_value

column1_value, column2_value, column3_value, column4_value, column5_value, column6_value

column1_value, column2_value, column3_value, column4_value, column5_value, column6_value
```

Comment: What exactly is your question for us? What is the problem with the code you show?

Comment: My goal is if a column does not exist in tds add it and place a value of nothing in list characteristics, At the moment I get list elements that already exist in the initial list

Comment: How do you know that a column doesn't exist?  For instance, if the first row only has one column, but the other rows have 2 or more, is the first row missing columns?  Or do you have a specific number of columns you are looking for?

Comment: shouldn't you loop through `tds`? it seems the code only captures two columns with `tds[0]` and `tds[1]`? Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Mendi Each row has two columns Name, Value Some tables have less. So I have a fixed list and when a Name, Value is missing I want to add it

Comment: is it ok if I add a sample html code so makes it more clear? you may need to modify my code afterward.

Comment: @Mehdi yes that is ok

Comment: @Mehdi Number of columns are the same , number of rows are variable

Comment: aha! so there are several tables with variable rows, not variable columns!, but you want to interpret them as column according to the `table_row` schema that you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197429/discussion-between-evridiki-and-mehdi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_table = r"""<html>
<body>
someother stuff
<table class="data-table">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>r1c2</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>r2c2</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_table, 'html.parser')

tb = soup.find('table', class_='data-table')

# dictionary of key-value characteristics in the html-table
character_dict = {
    tds[0].text.strip(): tds[1].text.strip()
    for tr in tb.find_all('tr')
    for tds in [tr.find_all('td')]
    if len(tds) == 2
}

# list of possible keys and their alternative synonyms:
table_rows =[['a','a1'],['b','b1'], ['z','z1']]

# standardized list of characteristics based on the standad table_rows:
character_list = []
for row in table_rows:
    for key in row:
        if key in character_dict:
            character_list.append((row[0], character_dict[key]))
            break
    else:
        # not found
        character_list.append((row[0], None))
```

The results in `character_list` is as follows:

```
[('a', 'r1c2'), ('b', 'r2c2'), ('z', None)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for something like `itertools.zip_longest` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)). Combine it with `zip()` to fill missing columns:

```
rows =[['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6'],
       ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'],
       ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5']]

from itertools import zip_longest

# fill missing columns with `-`
rows = [*zip(*zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue='-'))]

for row in rows:
    print(''.join('{: <10}'.format(d) for d in row))
```

Prints:

```
column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   
column1   column2   column3   column4   -         -         
column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   -
```

EDIT (example with tuples):

```
rows =((('a11', 'b'), ('a12', 'b'), ('a13', 'b'), ('a14', 'b'), ('a15', 'b'), ('a16', 'b')),
       (('a21', 'b'), ('a22', 'b'), ('a23', 'b'), ('a24', 'b')),
       (('a31', 'b'), ('a32', 'b'), ('a33', 'b'), ('a34', 'b'), ('a35', 'b')))

from itertools import zip_longest

# fill missing columns with ('X', 'X')
rows = [*zip(*zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue=('X', 'X')))]

for row in rows:
    print(''.join('{: <15}'.format(d[0] + '-' + d[1]) for d in row))
```

Prints:

```
a11-b          a12-b          a13-b          a14-b          a15-b          a16-b          
a21-b          a22-b          a23-b          a24-b          X-X            X-X            
a31-b          a32-b          a33-b          a34-b          a35-b          X-X
```

Comment: it should display a25 - X and a26 - X not X - X